# Maven with Java

Tags: java, scala, maven

When we compile a Maven project, by default the Java compiler is used to compile the source files. But nowhere this is mentioned in the POM file to instruct the compile phase to use the Java compiler.

Can someone please help how Maven automatically uses the Java compiler?

Suppose that we use maven to build a Scala programs, then how we can we instruct Maven to use the Scala compiler instead of Java?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please help how maven automatically uses java compiler?

Maven is designed to build and manage dependencies for a Java project. By default it will use a Java compiler.

If `mvn` is used to compile Scala programs instead of Java, then you'll need to use a maven plugin to compile Scala code. This [plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin) will work. Then code that is in `src/main/scala` will get compiled with the Scala compiler used by the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

By default Maven uses Java compiler included in the JDK.  As stated [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) the default is the class `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`.

If you want to override parameters for the compiler you can include your own plugin section:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and set the version of the compiler in properties:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

If you want to use Scala, there are [instructions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html) on how to do this.  You'll still need a Java compiler available.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala-module-dependency-sample/blob/master/maven-sample/pom.xml                                                                                                              When I see the POM file (under build section)  in GIT, I do not see that Scala (plugin) compile goal is tied to the compile phase. Just wondering how the Scala compiler is invoked. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: Generally when we use external plugins, under the build section either we give the coordinates; then we provide the id tag with the phase name (default-compile) which is there in super POM or else we give our own id and tie it with a default phase via <phase> tag. But in above, neither of them is given.

Answer (score 1):

There is maven-compile plugin which is active by default when your  pom packaging is jar:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html

Usually you do not have to tweak it at all